# uninstalling broken node packages for react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am working on a react native app and I had to install node and expo-cli to start the app but recently I have been having issues with running the app. When I run `npm start`, I get the error `expo: command not found` so I install the expo-cli using `npm install --global expo-cli` I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/{usr}/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR! dest /Users/{usr}/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-F3yBqKce
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/{usr}/.npm"
```

I ran the `sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/{usr}/.npm` command but it still does not work.

So I tried to uninstall node and start all over but the issue still persists. Does anyone know a way to fix these issues? Like is there a way I can reset my packages or something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should follow https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally Changing permissions outside your home folder on a multiuser system could easily break something. Installing Node.js packages with `sudo` is a security risk. Many packages contain malicious code.

Comment: What if you run `sudo npm install --global expo-cli`?

Comment: @ask4you 
when I run that I get this error:

`npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/{user}/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR! dest /Users/{user}/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-F3yBqKce
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/{usr}/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' -> '/Users/{user{/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-F3yBqKce'`

Comment: Try removing the `'/Users/{usr}/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/expo-cli'` folder  if exists and run it again